# How can I combine two PIVOTs that use different aggregate elements and the same spreading/grouping elements into a single row per ID?

Tags: t-sql

Couldn't find an exact duplicate question so please push one to me if you know of one.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjmca.jpg

See the screenshot (sorry for link, not enough rep). In the table I have ID, Cat, Awd, and Xmit.

I want a resultset where each row is a distinct ID plus the aggregate Awd and Xmit amounts for each Cat (so four add'l columns per ID).

Currently I'm using two CTEs, one to aggregate each of Awd and Xmit. Both make use of the PIVOT operator, using Cat to spread and ID to group. After each CTE does its thing, I'm INNER JOINing them on ID.

WITH CTE1 (ID, P_Awd, G_Awd) AS (
  SELECT ...
  FROM Table
  PIVOT(SUM(Awd) FOR Cat IN ('P', 'G'),
CTE2 ([same as CTE1 but replace "Awd" with "Xmit"])

SELECT ID, P_Awd, P_Xmit, G_Awd, G_Xmit
FROM CTE1 INNER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.ID = CTE2.ID

The output of this (greatly simplified) is two rows per ID, with each row holding the resultset of one CTE or the other.

What am I overlooking? Am I overcomplicating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here on one method via a CROSS APPLY

Also, this is assumes you don't need dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select ID
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (cat+'_Awd',Awd)
                             ,(cat+'_Xmit',Xmit)
                     ) B(Item,Value)
      ) src
Pivot (sum(Value) for Item in ([P_Awd],[P_XMit],[G_Awd],[G_XMit]) ) pvt
```

**Returns (Limited Set -- Best if you not use images for sample data)**

```
ID  P_Awd   P_XMit  G_Awd   G_XMit
1   1000    500     1000    0
2   2000    1500    500     500
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you kindly!

Comment: @MessyJesse Happy to help